# Unable to Receive Response from Lalamove API Request

Tags: angular

I am trying to make API request to Lalamove but I'm not receiving any response. I have followed the Lalamove API documentation([text](https://developers.lalamove.com/#introduction-change-driver) and implemented the request in my code.  when I make the request, I do not get successfull response.  i get response  message :An invalid response was received from the upstream server with  Status Code: 502

1. I have an Angular service (LalamoveService) responsible for making the API request to Lalamove.
2. I have correctly set the necessary headers, including 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', and 'Market', as instructed in the Lalamove API documentation.
3. I have generated the HMAC signature using the provided API key and secret.
4. I have tested the same request using Postman and received a successful response.
5. However, when I make the request from my Ionic project, I do not receive any response, and instead, I receive the error message mentioned above.

my project ionic with angular .so I make request using angular.
ionic version: 5.4.16.  angular version: 12.2.13

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import   crypto from 'crypto'
//import * as hashlib from "hashlib";
//const crypto = require('crypto');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LalamoveService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://rest.sandbox.lalamove.com'; // Lalamove API base URL
  private apiKey = 'pk_test_e1999e174b268de5e46e6e8438ef6fe0'; // Lalamove API key
  private secret = 'sk_test_U30oBq6HFPC6E7CN5EmZNaH3o/bJULbGXyf1nozvk727S1dD/aw80h9hZYBhM3U+'; // Lalamove API secret
  public region ='MY';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // //signature generate functon
  private generateSignature(method: string, path: string, body: string, time: string): string {
    const rawSignature = `${time}\r\n${method}\r\n${path}\r\n\r\n${body}`;
    const signature= CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(rawSignature, this.secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    console.log("checksignature",signature)
    return signature;
  }

//

  private createHeaders(method: string, path: string, body: string): HttpHeaders {

    //const timestamp= new Date().getTime().toString();// => `1545880607433`
    const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
    console.log("ch1");
    const signature= this.generateSignature(method,path, body,timestamp);

    

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization':`hmac ${this.apiKey}:${timestamp}:${signature}`,
      'Market':this.region
    });
  console.log("checkheaders",headers);
  console.log('Headers>: \n',headers.keys().map(name => `${name}: ${headers.get(name)}`).join('\n'));
    return headers;
  }
  
  //function for cities 
  public fetchCities() {
    const path = '/v3/cities';
    const headers = this.createHeaders('GET', path,JSON.stringify({ }));
    console.log("checkcityheder> \n",this.apiUrl,path,"\n",headers.keys().map(name => `${name}: ${headers.get(name)}`).join('\n'))
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}${path}`, { headers }) //.subscribe(resp => console.log(resp.));
  }
}


/// call cities function from aother page.
 this.LalamoveService.fetchCities().subscribe(
    
          (response) => {
            console.log('citiesresponse', response);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error('citiesresponse Error fetching quotations:', error);
          }
        );
```

on lalamove api documentary the said i need to amke header Authentication i make it.

when i make reques i need this headr formation,

Authorization: hmac pk_test_e1999e174b268de5e46e6e8438ef6fe0:1689441414:f3733a9840d37ab9825e8bf7c4ec7d78bb2bdac9287e777db9fa6d7605ba6e61
Market: MY

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUuE6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTsjG.png)

Here are my specific questions:

1. Are there any specific requirements or restrictions when making requests to the Lalamove server from a local environment or an Angular project?
2. Are there any considerations or specific configurations required for the headers or request setup when making the request from an Angular project?
3. What could be the possible reasons for not receiving a response from the Lalamove server when making the request from my Angular project?
4. Is there any additional setup or configuration that needs to be done to enable communication between my Angular project and the Lalamove server?
5. I have already confirmed that the request is working correctly using Postman, so the issue seems to be specific to my Angular project.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights that can help me resolve this issue and successfully receive a response from the Lalamove server in my Angular project.

Thank you in advance for your help!